# Attach term id to block or webform to display on a filtered page

Tags: taxonomy-terms, webforms

I think this is  a simple problem but I cannot find the answer/module/snippet or whatever.
I have a page which displays content with a certain taxonomy term

**www.website.com/#filter=.contact**

How do i easily add a term to a webform? So it will display on the contact page.
(maybe via a webform block)